# How to auto mapping network drive using GPO in 2k8

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, group-policy, network-share

I have a .bat file which is

```
net use z: \\....
```

to map network drive, and tested it with no problem under win xp

Then I try to put that as "startup script" under GPO (which is managed by 2k8 AD) -> Computer -> Policies -> Windows. After restarting computer, the script should be executed (I checked gpresult and the script is there), but the drive is not mounted. Any one have idea on what's happening ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using `User Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts > Logon`

You are mapping the the drive using the 'computer user account' rather than the users own account.

Edit: You could also use the new [Group Policy Preferences](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943729) in 2K8 to map a drive ( make sure you have the Group Policy Client Side Extensions installed on the machines you want apply the policy to)

Comment: Also, bear in mind that if you go the logon script route and are logged-on as an "Administrator" the "drive" still won't be available once Explorer starts. See: http://serverfault.com/questions/63738/networkmapping-script-vbs-vista-doesnt-work-xp-does/63756#63756

Comment: Good point, thx. My script is not working before coz my XP client havent installed the KB943729.

Answer (score 0):

If it's running as a startup script the computer account will need permissions to the network share, which I'm guessing it doesn't have. You need to set it as a logon script instead unless the former is your desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This site has a decent list of working logon scripts and bruteforce logon scripts that could help you out, there is also further detail on how to implement them through gpo. [Logon Scripts Site](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/logon_scripts.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site For mapping Network Drives using VB Script. : http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/Logon_HomeDir.htm

This helps if you have to use User Authentication aswell. And it seems you have a user Permission issue, so this should help you out.

I had the same problem a while back and got hold of that site(Will not let that site go either).

Answer (score 0):

I tried logon script, local GP few other methods but got strange results, the mapped drive would appear as disconnected when I log on. I tested with a batch file to write or read from the supposed mapped drive without logging on and none succeed. I cannot get rid of the disconnected mapped drive either!

I used MKLINK and this works perfectly without any issue and non profile dependent. this would create a soft link to your remote share via UNC and appears as a folder on your local drive everytime. I use this to share a remote UNC share for 2 servers sharing a config file for an application. I hope this works for you.

*mklink /D (comment: /D is for symbolic link, /H is a hardlink if your UNC is local drive) link-target*

for example:

```
mklink /D c:\SHARED_folder \\fileserver1\FOLDER_TOBE_SHARED
```

Comment: the task scheduler is also supposed to work in this scenario to map a drive at startup but i ran into permission problem even if the mapdrive batch file is ran under an admin account